# Динамическое изменение значения таймера в Android

Tags: java, android

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки, менялось нынешнее значение таймера?

```
private void mTimer1() {
        mCountTimer = new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTextField.setText( millisUntilFinished / 1000 + " sec");
            }

            public void onFinish() {    
                }
        }.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете изменить время у таймера. Нужно создавать новый:

```
long countDownInterval = 1000;
long countdownPeriod = 5000;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (mCountTimer != null) {
        mCountTimer.cancel();
        mCountTimer = null;
    }

    countdownPeriod =+ countDownInterval;

    createAndStart();

    return true;
}

private void createAndStart() {
    mCountTimer = new CountDownTimer(countdownPeriod, countDownInterval) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            countdownPeriod -= countDownInterval;
            mTextField.setText( millisUntilFinished / 1000 + " sec");
        }

        public void onFinish() {    
        }

    }.start();
}
```

Comment: То есть вам нужно, чтобы таймер после нажатия уходил на начальное значение? Тогда уберите строчку: countdownPeriod =+ 10000;

Comment: Нет, то есть, вот, к примеру, когда на таймере будет 5 сек, я нажимаю на кнопку и, судя по вашему коду, будет уже начинаться отсчет с 16, а не с 6, я правильно понял?

Comment: Изначально вопрос звучал: как изменять время счетчика. В моем примере при каждом нажатии создается новый счетчик на 10 сек больше. Первый счетчик - 15 сек, потом - 25, 35, 45... Вы что хотите?

Comment: я хочу, чтоб при нажатии на кнопку менялось нынешнее, а не изначальное. К примеру, на значени 6, нажимаю на кнопку и значение стало 7, еще раз 8, подожду когда будет 4, нажму и станет 5.

Comment: Добавил исправления